# Добавление в локальное хранилище (localStorage) значения со стилями

Tags: javascript, localstorage

Есть, допустим, такая ситуация. Необходимо в localStorage добавить "Hello, world!", но чтобы после перезагрузки текст оставался красным цветом. Возможно ли такое сделать? Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким образом или перенаправьте на похожие темы.

Код самый простейший, просто для примера:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

.red {
   color: red;
}



</style>
</head>

<body>

<div id='wrapper'></div>

<script>

'use strict'
let wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');

let someText = document.createElement('h1');
let someBtn = document.createElement('input');
let someBtn2 = document.createElement('input');

someBtn.setAttribute('type', 'button');
someBtn.setAttribute('value', 'Change color');
someBtn2.setAttribute('type', 'button');
someBtn2.setAttribute('value', 'Add to local storage');

someText.innerHTML = 'Hello, world!';
wrapper.appendChild(someText);
wrapper.appendChild(someBtn);
wrapper.appendChild(someBtn2);

someBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    someText.className = 'red';
});

someBtn2.addEventListener('click', () => {

    JSON.stringify(localStorage.setItem('text', someText.textContent));
});






</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если переключать именно класс с цветом, то можно так:

```js
    let wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');

    let someText = document.createElement('h1');
    let someBtn = document.createElement('input');
    let someBtn2 = document.createElement('input');

    someBtn.setAttribute('type', 'button');
    someBtn.setAttribute('value', 'Change color');
    someBtn2.setAttribute('type', 'button');
    someBtn2.setAttribute('value', 'Add to local storage');

    someText.innerHTML = 'Hello, world!';
    wrapper.appendChild(someText);
    wrapper.appendChild(someBtn);
    wrapper.appendChild(someBtn2);

    let NameOfClass = "red"; // Название класса

    let col = localStorage.getItem('color1'); //Проверяем параметр в хранилище
    if (col){ //Если есть
        someText.className = col; //Присваиваем класс
    }

    someBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
        someText.className = NameOfClass;
    });

    someBtn2.addEventListener('click', () => {
        JSON.stringify(localStorage.setItem('text', someText.textContent));
        localStorage.setItem('color1', NameOfClass); //Сохраняем класс в хранилище
    });
```

```css
        .red {
            color: red;
        }
```

```html
<body>

<div id='wrapper'></div>
```

Вариант с цветами, а не с классами.

```js
    let wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');

    let someText = document.createElement('h1');
    let someBtn = document.createElement('input');
    let someBtn2 = document.createElement('input');

    someBtn.setAttribute('type', 'button');
    someBtn.setAttribute('value', 'Change color');
    someBtn2.setAttribute('type', 'button');
    someBtn2.setAttribute('value', 'Add to local storage');

    someText.innerHTML = 'Hello, world!';
    wrapper.appendChild(someText);
    wrapper.appendChild(someBtn);
    wrapper.appendChild(someBtn2);

    let color = ""; // Создаём переменную

    let col = localStorage.getItem('color1'); //Проверяем параметр в хранилище
    if (col){ //Если есть
        someText.style.color = col; //Присваиваем цвет
    }

    someBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
        color = "red"; // Задаём нужный цвет
        someText.style.color = color;
    });

    someBtn2.addEventListener('click', () => {
        JSON.stringify(localStorage.setItem('text', someText.textContent));
        localStorage.setItem('color1', color); //Сохраняем класс в хранилище
    });
```

```html
<div id='wrapper'></div>
```

Пример с несколькими цветами:

```js
        let wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');
        let wrapper1 = document.getElementById('wrapper');
        let wrapper2 = document.getElementById('wrapper');
    
    
        let someText = document.createElement('h1');
        let someText1 = document.createElement('h2');
        let someText2 = document.createElement('h3');
        let someBtn = document.createElement('input');
        let someBtn2 = document.createElement('input');
    
        someBtn.setAttribute('type', 'button');
        someBtn.setAttribute('value', 'Change color');
        someBtn2.setAttribute('type', 'button');
        someBtn2.setAttribute('value', 'Add to local storage');
    
        someText.innerHTML = 'Hello, world1!';
        wrapper.appendChild(someText);
        wrapper.appendChild(someBtn);
        wrapper.appendChild(someBtn2);
    
        someText1.innerHTML = 'Hello, world2!';
        wrapper1.appendChild(someText1);
    
        someText2.innerHTML = 'Hello, world3!';
        wrapper2.appendChild(someText2);
    
        let color = []; // Создаём переменную
    
        let col = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('color1'));
        if (col){ //Если есть
            someText.style.color = col[0]; //Присваиваем цвет
            someText1.style.color = col[1]; //Присваиваем цвет
            someText2.style.color = col[2]; //Присваиваем цвет
        }
    
        someBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
            color.push("red"); // Задаём нужный цвет
            someText.style.color = color[0];
            color.push("blue"); // Задаём нужный цвет
            someText1.style.color = color[1];
            color.push("orange"); // Задаём нужный цвет
            someText2.style.color = color[2];
        });
    
        someBtn2.addEventListener('click', () => {
            JSON.stringify(localStorage.setItem('text', someText.textContent));
            localStorage.setItem('color1', JSON.stringify(color)); //Сохраняем класс в хранилище
        });
```

```html
<div id='wrapper'></div>
<div id='wrapper1'></div>
<div id='wrapper2'></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо. А если вот таких элементов 4, допустим. Красный, зеленый, синий, желтый. Всем классы сохранять, или есть способ проще?

Comment: @faceVB можно сохранять и сам цвет. Но в примере Вы указывали именно класс. Мало ли там ещё какие-либо параметры у Вас будут ) По сути без разницы, что задавать цвет в `css`, что просто прописывать его в `js`, Вам же всё-равно надо эти цвета проставить элементам.

Comment: То есть, если класс не использовать, каким образом добавить цвет, чтобы он применился именно на этом элементе?

Comment: @faceVB Добавил в ответ(снизу). Постарайтесь, пожалуйста, предоставлять пример тот, который Вам нужен. (Например, если нужен класс, то в примере класс, если нужен цвет, то в примере цвет).

Comment: @faceVB добавил ещё пример(в самом низу) с несколькими цветами.

Comment: Ок, понял, то есть лист просто создать. С другими свойствами, например, можно также? Я имею ввиду text-transform или text-decoration.

Comment: @Да, конечно можно. Если хотите, чтобы текст сохранял свои индивидуальные параметры типа шрифта, цвета и так далее - лучше сделать классом и так же добавлять в localstorage как в последнем примере, только классами, чтобы много параметров вручную не прописывать в `js`. А так всё будет компактно )

Comment: Понял. Спасибо огромное!